# Certificate Authentication with Paw App

Tags: client-certificates, paw-app

In my case I want to test a rest-api protected by certificate-authentication.
I want to use the Paw-App to test this REST-API but I can't find a way to insert/upload my client-certificate and the truststore (jks or pkcs12).

I wonder if it is possible in the Paw-App to enable certificate authentication and how to do that, or if there are any plans to implement that besides OAuth and HTTP-Basic-Auth?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet, Paw doesn't support client-side SSL certificates yet. That's planned though, we want to add it in a future version.

Answer (score 2):

Paw now supports client certificates! :)
https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/auth/ssl-client-certificates